# loading image from url starting with double forward slash in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, uiimage

I am extracting image url from html img tag's src using regular expression.
Everything is fine except the url starting with double forward slash `//`.

As it is working fine in html but in objective c the image is not loading at all.
below is the url which i am getting to display default image.

```
//www.gravatar.com/avatar/8deed2d5074b282325d6f151d6614b71?d=mm&s=200&r=G
```

The code i am using to load the image is as below

```
_userProfile.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgString]]];
```

where the `userProfile` is `UIImage` object and the `imgString` contains the image url

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: use thislink http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8deed2d5074b282325d6f151d6614b71%3Fd=mm&s=200&r=G , not this link because this link is local  file:///www.gravatar.com/avatar/8deed2d5074b282325d6f151d6614b71%3Fd=mm&s=200&r=G. @lftikhar

Answer (score 0):

You need a base URL like you get on a website.

```
// Base URL is the base path to your web service.
// Something like  https://base.webservice.com/ or whatever.
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://base.webservice.com/"];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imgString relativeToURL:baseURL];
_userProfile.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
```